# Synonym / merge request: [team] → [teamwork]

Tags: support, status-declined, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Could we merge [team](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team) with [teamwork](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teamwork)?

Went quickly through their questions, they seem to discuss exactly the same topic. And they are high on my list of cleanup candidates, merging them into a single tag would help a bit.

Comment: is there a tag not on your cleanup list?

Comment: And I just [status-declined] myself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with the merge. Like [SnOrfus pointed out in a comment](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3071/4), there are two things to consider: the structure/organization of the team and the relationships between members of the team. However, I think there might be a better tag (or even better tags) than "team" and "teamwork", but I'm not sure what they are at this point. There is, however, a need for tags to differentiate between structuring and organizing a team and working on/with a team as they are very different concepts.

Although, there is another side to the argument. This isn't a site about organizational behavior, social psychology, or sociology. Do we really need to differentiate between these concepts on a site that is ultimately about software development? Perhaps not, and the merge should be the other way: [teamwork](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teamwork) into [team](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think [team](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team) is the same as [teamwork](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teamwork)

I see [team](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team) as being about interactions between the team, team dynamics, or team composition, while [teamwork](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teamwork) is about working together as a team to accomplish a similar goal.

Comment: I don't get it. `interactions between the team, team dynamics, or team composition` are teamwork activities & processes. What is the value of having two tags? Even if there are subtle differences, are those differences on topic? And are there any example questions that fit in the one tag and not the other?

Comment: @YannisRizos Sure there's differences. There was [a question asked a few days ago](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/133565/1130) where the `team` tag was appropriate, but not `teamwork` because the question was about the team roles, not necessarily teamwork. Just go through the questions tagged with `[team]` and see if you could apply `[teamwork]` to all of them

Comment: `the question was about the team roles, not necessarily teamwork` I honestly don't see any difference. How can anything be about a team and not be about working with a team at the same time? Team roles are just a definition of your responsibilities when working in a team, they are not a concept that could possibly stand on its own.

Comment: @YannisRizos: For example... **Team**: hierarchy, structure, roles, ie. organizational **Teamwork**: communication, collaboration, ie. interpersonal.

Comment: @SnOrfus Thanks for clarifying.